# Systems of polynomial equations involving sums of equal powers

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Given the following system of polynomial equations:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lclclcr}
x & + & y & + & z & = & 1
\\
x^{2} & + & y^{2} & + & z^{2} & = & 14
\\
x^{3} & + & y^{3} & + & z^{3} & = & 36
\end{array}\right.
$$
What is $x^{5} + y^{5} + z^{5}\ {\large ?}$ .

---

How should I approach this? Is there a general formula for this kind of system?

Comment: Try using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TBVeuOcY1w) approach by blackpenredpen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p=x+y+z$, $q=xy+yz+zx$, $r=xyz$. So we have
$$\begin{cases}
p=1\\p^2-2q=14\\p^3-3pq+3r=36
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
p = 1\\q = -\frac{13}{2}\\ r = \frac{31}{6}
\end{cases}$$
By consecutive eliminating the highest powers terms we get
[$$x^5+y^5+z^5-(x+y+z)^5+5(xy+yz+xz)(x+y+z)^3-5(xy+yz+xz)^2(x+y+z)-5(x+y+z)^2xyz+5(xy+yz+xz)xyz=0$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+x%5E5%2By%5E5%2Bz%5E5-%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E5%2B5%28xy%2Byz%2Bxz%29%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E3-5%28xy%2Byz%2Bxz%29%5E2%28x%2By%2Bz%29-5%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E2xyz%2B5%28xy%2Byz%2Bxz%29xyz)
In other words, $x^5+y^5+z^5=p^5-5qp^3+5q^2p+5p^2r-5qr$ [$=\frac{877}{2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%3D1%2C+p%5E2-2q%3D14%2C+p%5E3-3pq%2B3r%3D36%2C+p%5E5-5qp%5E3%2B5q%5E2p%2B5p%5E2r-5qr%3Dx)

Answer (score 5):

The requested exponent does not matter that much. Each of the three is a root of the same
$$  6 t^3 - 6 t^2  - 39 t - 31, $$
one real and two complex conjugates, but we don't need them. Each also obeys
$$  6 t^{n+3} - 6 t^{n+2}  - 39 t^{n+1} - 31 t^n, $$ so that $a_n=x^n + y^n + z^n$  is a sequence with linear recurrence
$$ a_{n+3} = a_{n+2} + \frac{13}{2} a_{n+1} + \frac{31}{6} a_n  $$ or
$$ a_1 = 1, \; a_2 = 14, \; a_3 = 36, \; a_4 = \frac{793}{6}, \; $$
$$ a_5 = \frac{877}{2}, \; a_6 = \frac{17803}{12}, \; a_7 = \frac{180601}{36}, \; a_8 = \frac{1218641}{72}, \; $$

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thanks. For a while there this type of question was quite frequent on this site, so I had a memory that this sort of thing ought to work; then I answered one within the past few months and the details turned out to be easy enough.

Comment: found the previous time I did this, that OP was not enthusiastic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749238/find-xnynzn-general-solution/3749331#3749331

Comment: How do you find that they are all zeros of that polynomial?

Comment: @WillJagy What do you mean by “Each of the three is a root of the same [polynomial]”? The exponents I gave (1, 2, and 3) aren’t roots of that polynomial.